# Add downloadable product to a customer without ordering

Tags: customer, downloadable

I want to award a downloadable product to a certain customer. Currently the rule is normally allow downloadable products to customers who bought it. How do I allow that customer manually to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a product directly to a customer without an order.

You could create orders with 0 total automatically (giving that the downloadable product is also price 0) without notifying the customer.